# How to find signature of specific PGI functions used for OpenACC?

Tags: openacc, pgi, pgi-accelerator

How can I find the signature of specific functions used for OpenACC by PGI compiler?

For instance, `__pgi_uacc_enter` or `__pgi_uacc_launch` functions.

Is there any documentation or header files to find the signature. Or even some documentation regarding not only their signature but also their functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the signature of those are exposed because they're not things a user calls, but rather they're used from generated code. I'd bet that you're not using the -ta (or -acc) flag at *link* time.  If you link with the OpenACC flag it should provide those symbols.

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I was looking for: accessing functions that are called by `acc` directives. Regarding whether I used `-ta` or `-acc` when linking or not: actually I am. I used `-acc -ta=nvidia` when compiling and linking my code, and I saw those in-home functions using `nm` tool.